# FirebaseApp is not initialized Android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-messaging

el problema que tengo es que el día de ayer actualicé mi Android studio y me pidió que actualizara el gradle, así que lo hice pero ahora al abrir mi app me da el siguiente error en el HomeActivity.kt

```
Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.ejemploApp.app.com Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
```

Busque información y dice que debo iniciar la instancia de Firebase Messaging que es la que estoy implementando para notificaciones push con esto:

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
```

Pero no funciona sigue dando el mismo error, ¿alguna ayuda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Justamente me pasó algo similar hace unos días, fue por actualizar el gradle a la version 4.10 desde la version 4.0 y también la version de kotlin.

La solución es muy sencilla. en tu Android Studio debes actualizar todas las librerias a la ultima version, sobre todo las que tienen que ver con kotlin gms-services y firebase.

Por ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en esa imagen puedes ver que hay algunas dependencias resaltadas, ese es un proyecto viejo que tengo y aprovecho para mostrarte. Si pones tu cursor encima de ese texto, te saldrá un mensaje de

> "A newer version of xxx than is available: xxxxx"

y te dice el numero de la nueva versión, cambialo y luego sincroniza las dependencias, en los dos build.gradle de tu gradle script.

Con eso debería funcionar, si no, tendrías que revisar tu implementación de push notifications.

Comment: Oh, no sabía eso. ok estoy actualizando las dependencias

Comment: Pues sí era eso, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Como complemento a la respuesta, además de [actualizar las library](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?hl=es-419), el mensaje :

> Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process
>   com.ejemploApp.app.com Make sure to call
>   FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

Puedes ser causado también (que al parecer no es tu caso) como indica el mensaje de error por no inicializar Firebase,

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
```

Comment: Así es, eso intenté al principio pero no funcionó y ahora funciona mi App sin usar esa linea, necesito entender mejor como funciona.